# Debugging embedded application in vim

Tags: debugging, vim, gdb, embedded, gdbserver

I'm trying to debug a remote embedded system.

On the target machine I run:

```
gdbserver localhost:port myapp
```

And on the host machine I run:

```
gdb-multiarch myapp
(gdb) target remote ip-address:port
```

It works and I can debug normally.

I'd like to debug this embedded program in vim as I do using `Termdebug` to debug normal program.

Is there a way to run `gdb-multiarch` when calling `Termdebug`? Or is there a better alternative?

Comment: See if `:help g:termdebugger` helps.

Comment: I think there is a mistake: `Sorry, no help for g:termdebugger`

Comment: You may not have a recent enough Vim, in which case the suggestion is moot.

Comment: I have version 8.1

Comment: The mechanism changed since then, [apparently](https://github.com/vim/vim/blame/bfb2bb16bc69441fa3ec13caacb2c94637a8a0ec/runtime/doc/terminal.txt#L1401-L1403).

Answer (score 3):

This question is quite old but I will answer anyways in case anyone else is looking for this information.

I'm using VIM 8.1 and there you can specify which debugger to use with this command:

```
let g:termdebugger='gdb-multiarch'
```

If you want this permanent add it to your .vimrc file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, load the term debugger plugin

```
:packadd termdebug
```

Then you can use the debugger the way you know how

```
:Termdebug
```

[It's in the docs](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/terminal.txt#L1165-L1172)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this was not my quesiton. I already know these commands. My question was how to run `gdb-multiarch` instead of the standard `gdb` when running `:Termdebug`.